# Opencv VideoCapture speed slow for people detecting

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection, image-recognition

I am using **Python 2.7.11** and **opencv 2.4.9**. I have two prgram for the video **face detecting** and **people detecting**. However, it is smooth for the face detecting but slow or the people detecting.

Face Detecting:

```
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\opencv\sources\data\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        frame,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

People Detecting:

```
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
hog.setSVMDetectorcv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()    

    (rects, weights) = hog.detectMultiScale(
        frame, 
        winStride=(4, 4),
        padding=(8, 8), 
        scale=1.05
    )

    rects = np.array([[x, y, x + w, y + h] for (x, y, w, h) in rects])

    pick = non_max_suppression(rects, probs=None, overlapThresh=0.65)


    for (xA, yA, xB, yB) in pick:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (xA, yA), (xB, yB), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow("Before NMS", frame)

    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Ops, I want to ask how to speed up the people recognition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Human detection is a very time consuming algorithm. You check the algorithm in detail [here](http://mccormickml.com/2013/05/09/hog-person-detector-tutorial/). We can change the arguments passing to `hog` function. Like `winStride`, `padding` and `scale` it's change the speed of algorithm. Only do the fine tuning else it's effects the result.

Or you can implement an another step before the People detection. Like motion detection,then only check for the people if there is any kind of motions is occur. You can find the python code for motion detection [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/05/25/basic-motion-detection-and-tracking-with-python-and-opencv/). So it's remove the unnecessary check for people.